# Bash 19 chars disappear with no reasons

Tags: linux, bash

I trying to make a batch script to compress my audio files and I face a really weird issue.

Here is my code :

```
#!/bin/bash

qscale=$1
input=$2
output=$3
inputSize=$((${#input}+1))

find "$input" -type f -name "*.flac" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' a
do
    path=${a:inputSize}
    echo "Working on $path"
#    ffmpeg -i "$a" -qscale:a $qscale "$output/${path[@]/%flac/mp3}" &>/dev/null
done
```

Here is a result example :

```
Working on 09 - Groove #2 (instrumental studio outtake).flac
Working on 07 - Blues for Allah Sand Castles and Glass Camels Unusual Occurrences in the Desert.flac
Working on 12 - Proto 18 Proper (instrumental studio outtake).flac
Working on 04 - The Music Never Stopped.flac
Working on 13 - Hollywood Cantana (studio outtake).flac
...
```

If I uncomment the `ffmpeg` line, here is the result for the same folder :

```
Working on 09 - Groove #2 (instrumental studio outtake).flac
Working on h Sand Castles and Glass Camels Unusual Occurrences in the Desert.flac
Working on 12 - Proto 18 Proper (instrumental studio outtake).flac
Working on r Stopped.flac
Working on 13 - Hollywood Cantana (studio outtake).flac
...
```

One file on two misses its 19th first chars ! And I've no idea why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncommenting the ffmpeg line and running [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) on it reports this:

```
Line 12:
    ffmpeg -i "$a" -qscale:a $qscale "$output/${path[@]/%flac/mp3}" &>/dev/null
    ^-- SC2095: Add < /dev/null to prevent ffmpeg from swallowing stdin.
```

Try again with

```
ffmpeg -i "$a" -qscale:a $qscale "$output/${path[@]/%flac/mp3}" &>/dev/null < /dev/null
```

`ffmpeg`, along with `ssh` and `mplayer`, are notorious for stealing stdin from `while read` loops.